# How to page curl for pdf file

Tags: android

hi i m new in android page curl application, i show the pdf file using mupdf opensource via. here using intent action view, so only scroll is working but i need page curl.if any body know the answer please help this concept. thank you.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mAlertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        if (core == null) {
            core = (MuPDFCore)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();

            if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("FileName")) {
                mFileName = savedInstanceState.getString("FileName");
            }
        }
        if (core == null) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                Uri uri = intent.getData();
                if (uri.toString().startsWith("content://media/external/file")) {
                    // Handle view requests from the Transformer Prime's file manager
                    // Hopefully other file managers will use this same scheme, if not
                    // using explicit paths.
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{"_data"}, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(0));
                    }
                }
                core = openFile(Uri.decode(uri.getEncodedPath()));
            }
            if (core != null && core.needsPassword()) {
                requestPassword(savedInstanceState);
                return;
            }
        }
        if (core == null)
        {
            AlertDialog alert = mAlertBuilder.create();
            alert.setTitle(R.string.open_failed);
            alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Dismiss",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
            alert.show();
            return;
        }

        createUI(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: i want to implement curl effect in mupdf.can u know that how can i do this ?...thanks

Comment: @kyogs have you found solution to you problem please guide me also if got the answer

Comment: @kyogs As same as above comment!

Comment: @Passion How about yourself?! Did you find solution to implement curl effect in mupdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the code from here [android_page_curl](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl) and [link](http://techie-manoj.com/?p=146)

Comment: THis  https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl downloading code and also site are very usefull to me thank you very much.

Comment: @Sathish Kumar, Aerrow...the links provide doesnot use rendered mupdf page for page curl so how does it solved your problem plz guide me also

Comment: @SathishKumar As same as above comment!

Answer (score 1):

From here you can download the source code for [page curl effect](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/source/checkout).

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10598343/614807) for checkout source code from Google Code.

Comment: And how using this in muPFD? There is no body whose merged these two stuff together?! really!